# Finding out wrongly classified instances when using WEKA

Tags: weka

I am using GUI version of WEKA and I am classifying using the Naive Bayes. Can anyone please let me know how to find out which instances are misclassified.

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to classify tab in Weka explorer
2. Click more options...
3. Check output predictions
4. Click OK

Hope that helps.

Comment: Informative, however ss far as I can see that doesn't really work when using cross-validation, as there is no way to link Weka's output of misclassified instances to the original instances

Comment: It seems you are missing an ID attribute. Check the answer from @Menezes Sousa. Step 6 was the key for me.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this very same problem earlier and I tackle it just fine now. 
What I do, is the following:

1. Make one String attribute that assigns each instance a unique ID. I
   have assigned the names of the documents to each of my instances.
2. Generate the WEKA supported .arff file.
3. Whenever you have to run a classifier on this .arff data, you will notice that you have to exclude the Instance ID attribute. If you don't do this, Weka will pop-up an error saying that the classifier cannot process String attributes. Instead of excluding, run filter StringToNominal on the InstanceID.
4. Now, as said by @Rushdi, click "More Options" on the classify tab.
5. Check Output predictions on the "Classifier Evaluation Options" pop-up.
6. Enter the Attribute number of the Instance ID in the "Output additional attributes" box.
7. Run the classifier on the whole data, excluding the Instance ID attribute. (Most classifiers have this as an option called "StartSet" in "Ranker" for example which I use along with SMO classifier.)
8. If you've done everything properly so far, you will see all the instances listed along with their real and predicted output values and also the Instance ID which can tell you exactly which documents were incorrectly classified.

Hope this helps someone.
Good Luck!

Comment: This would seem ideal. However Simple Logistic has no option StartSet

Comment: Use a FilteredClassifier.

Answer (score 0):

In your output there should be a incorrectly classified section with a number and percentage, that should be it. The red box in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbrQ6.png) is what you're looking for. **Edit**: Original image source [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/explorer_screenshots/ClassifyPanel.png)

Comment: I think s/he wanted to know if it is possible to see individual misclassified instances.

Comment: Yup. That's my fault. After rereading it, you're definitely right.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

1. Decompile the official weka.jar
2. Search into the library the classification that you want to test for know how it works and determinate what instances are misclassified.